# How do I calculate the distribution of an amount of dice throws?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

Two players are throwing a (fair) dice in turns. Player 1 wins if he gets a 1 and Player 2 wins if he gets a 5 or a 6. If one of the players wins, the other one continues until he gets the required number.

If $X$ and $Y$ are the amount of throws of Player 1 and 2, how can I calculate the distributions of $X$ and $Y$?

I assume the distribution of getting any number is completely uniform (i.e $\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{6}$), but how do I formulate this in regards to the number of throws?
It seems to me that both distributions would be the same.

Comment: 1) If player 1 wins, player 2 will then have to roll until he gets a 5 or 6, with an expected number of 3 rolls. If player 2 wins, then player 1 will have to roll until he gets a 1, with an expected number of 6 rolls. So clearly they will have different distributions.2) Do we always consider player 1 rolling first? This will also affect the distributions. 3) My approach would be to calculate the expected number of rolls remaining in the game on player 1's turns, for both scenarios of winning and losing. same for player 2. You'll probably get a recursive formula which you can then solve for.

Comment: From your description, it doesn’t seem like the actions of either player affect the other. Each keeps rolling until the target number is hit.

Comment: @amd that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

According to your description, $X$ and $Y$ are statistically independent of one another. If player 1 at some point gets the number 1, only player 2 needs to continue. Likewise, if player 2 at some points gets the number 5 or 6, only player 1 needs to continue. This corresponds to a scenario in which both players keep throwing the dice until they hit (one of) the right number(s).

For $X$ to equal $n$, player 1 must fail on the first $n-1$ turns and succeed on the $n^{th}$ turn. This corresponds to a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution):

$$P[X=n] = \bigg(\frac{5}{6}\bigg)^{n-1}\frac{1}{6}$$

Similarly, we find:

$$P[Y=n] = \bigg(\frac{4}{6}\bigg)^{n-1}\frac{2}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks! One question, with these two formulas, wouldn't it mean that the probability of winning for either side decrease as $n$ increases? Or how should I interpret this?

Comment: The probability of getting the required number remains the same on each turn, i.e. $\frac{1}{6}$ and $\frac{2}{6}$. However, the probability of getting the right number for the first time on the $n^{th}$ turn (first having lost on each of the previous $n-1$ turns) decreases with $n$.